# React Native: How to hide keyboard after touch id password input

Tags: react-native

How do I hide a keyboard when a  is active and auto-filled after a touch-id verification?

Basically I am loading a username and password combination and I want to hide the keyboard once that process is done.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using react-native-touch-id [rn-touch-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-touch-id)  so now when there is success in fingertprint id scan you can just simply do  :

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';

 TouchID.authenticate('to demo this react-native component', optionalConfigObject)
      .then(success => {
        Keyboard.dismiss()
      })
      .catch(error => {
         Keyboard.dismiss()
      });
```

hope it helps.